# xamdatetimeeditor set default current time and date

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

How to set default current time and date in xamdatetimeeditor instead of default blank?

My code below won't show the current date and time.
It will be blank until date time are chosen from xamDateTimeEditor drop down.

In xaml

```
<igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor 
        Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Date" 
        Visibility="{Binding datetimeVisible, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}"
        Height="23" Validation.Error="Validation_Error" Mask="yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss" 
        DropDownButtonDisplayMode="Always"  DisplayMode="IncludeBoth" 
        Value="{Binding DateInitial, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
        Text ="{Binding DateSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}">
    <igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor.ValueConstraint>
        <igEditors:ValueConstraint 
                MaxInclusive="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" ValidateAsType="DateTime" />
    </igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor.ValueConstraint>
</igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor>
```

In code behind

```
public string Error
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        string result = null;
        if (columnName == "DateSelected")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateSelected))
            {
                result = "Please select date";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public DateTime DateInitial
{
    get { return this.dateInitial; }
    set
    {
        this.dateInitial = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
        Trace.WriteLine("dateInitial !!!! " + dateInitial);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out :
Add NullText to the `<igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor`

```
NullText="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{}{0:yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss}'}"
```